# What nanometer laser has the least effect on a blue cotton cloth?

Tags: optics, laser

What Nanometer of a 10-watt laser at 5 feet would have the least amount of burn effect on a color blue cotton cloth?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say. "Blue" is vague, nanometers are precise. A refection spectrum of the actual material could be illuminating: look for the wavelength where the reflection is greatest.